# Преобразование `null` в `0` (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Допустим у нас есть вот такой код на `javascript`.

```
var years = prompt('Сколько вам лет?', 100);
console.log(years);
```

И как мы знаем после того как мы нажмем на `cancel` в модальном окне, наша функция вернет значение `null`.

Но мне в этом случае нужно что бы в переменной `years` было значение `0`.

Конечно можно это сделать к примеру так:

```
if(years == null){
  years = 0;
}
```

Но мне нужно сделать это без каких либо проверок на `null`.

Как можно этого добиться ?

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, откуда такая ненависть к проверкам?)

Comment: @andreymal особенно если учесть, то ввести могут и строку, то остутствие проверок кажется несколько  странным

Comment: @andreymal я пример дал для вопроса.)))))

Comment: @teran В реальном коде не надо будет других проверок.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` автоматически преобразует null в 0, заодно и строчку спарсит в число.

```js
var x = +prompt("Сколько вам лет?",100);
alert(x);
```

Либо вам необходимо сделать своё диалоговое окно, которое при отмене будет возвращать 0, либо вообще ничего не будет возвращать, а переменную зададите сразу равную 0.

Разумеется в реальности так делать смысла нет.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var years = prompt('Сколько вам лет?', 100) || 0;
console.log(years);
```

Comment: `+0`  как вариант

Comment: Это то же проверка.

Comment: @StackOverflow тогда опишите ваши критерии "проверки" в вопросе.

Comment: Я описал, без каких либо сравнений.

Answer (score 1):

Для преобразования к числу нужно вызвать внутреннюю функцию [ToNumber](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-tonumber).

Данная функция вызывается во многих местах:

1. [`Number (value)`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-number-constructor-number-value)
2. Унарные операторы [`+`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator) и [`-`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-unary-minus-operator)
3. Бинарные операторы [`+`, `-`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-additive-operators), [`*`, `/`, `%`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-multiplicative-operators), [`**`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-exp-operator)
4. Постфиксные операторы [`--`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-postfix-decrement-operator), [`++`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-postfix-increment-operator)
5. Различный битовые операции: [`&`, `|`, `^`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-binary-bitwise-operators), [`~`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-bitwise-not-operator)
6. Операторы сдвига: [`>>`, `<<`, `>>>`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-bitwise-shift-operators)

**Важно:** операторы сдвига и битовые операции приводят входной аргумент к беззнаковому и знаковому **32-х**-битному числу.